# C# Treeview doesn't refresh after moving nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

In my windows application I have a treeview. I made custum buttons to move a node downwards. This is what happens when a button is clicked:

```
Node destNode = tvCategories.SelectedNode.NextNode;
Node srcNode = tvCategories.SelectedNode;
Node parentNode = srcNode.Parent;

// Switch nodes
parentNode.Nodes[destNode.Index] = srcNode;
parentNode.Nodes[srcNode.Index] = destNode;
```

The code works fine, but my treeview isn't updated. I don't see the switch of the nodes.

`tvCategories.Refresh()` or `tvCategories.Invalidate()` or `tvCategories.Update()` doesn't work.

Anybody knows how to fix this?

PS: I'm using a 3rd party treeview of DevComponents.

Comment: did you try `Application.DoEvents()` ?

Comment: Where do you suggest to place that line?

Comment: @Martjin at the end of your click action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove one node and to insert it again:

```
Node destNode = tvCategories.SelectedNode.NextNode;
// Check for null (what happens, if the last node is selected?)

// Switch nodes
destNode.Parent.Nodes.Remove( destNode );
destNode.Parent.Nodes.Insert( tvCategories.SelectedNode.Index, destNode );
```

Comment: Thanks this way it works fine :) (there's a small bug in your code, it is destNode.Parent.Nodes.Remove())

Comment: @tanascius I usually don't do that but I'm totally stuck can you help me on that related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588519/c-sharp-treeview-doesnt-always-display-its-content
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Setting Focus on the Treeview will cause a refresh as I have found
by using

> TreeView.Focus()

Comment: That worked for me with a simular issue, thanks.